# Wordpress editor error: TypeError: He.cancel is not a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, typeerror, editor, wordpress-gutenberg

I am getting weird error when trying to add new post. Editor says "The editor has encountered an unexpected error." and I get options: Attempt recovery, Copy post text, Copy error.

Error:

```
TypeError: He.cancel is not a function
    at wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=d8cf5b24f99c64ae47d6:9:3694
    at cr (wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:67115)
    at gr (wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:69508)
    at Br (wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:80574)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:7431)
    at xn (wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:29950)
    at Ar (wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:78535)
    at Pr (wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:74654)
    at wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:30173
    at unstable_runWithPriority (wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:7431)
```

Also many errors in console:

```
react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9 TypeError: He.cancel is not a function
    at data.min.js?ver=d8cf5b24f99c64ae47d6:9:3694
    at cr (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:67115)
    at gr (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:69508)
    at Br (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:80574)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (react.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:7431)
    at xn (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:29950)
    at Ar (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:78535)
    at Pr (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:74654)
    at react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:30173
    at unstable_runWithPriority (react.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:7431)
```

If i enable Gutenberg plugin it works ok. I tried to disable all plugins with same error. Tried to downgrade WP with no luck...

Any idea?
Thanks

Disabled all plugins, downgrade, cleared cache

Comment: Disable all the browser extensions and then check if extensions are conflicting something.

Comment: Nope. Tried with different browsers and different computers...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue this morning. Just reinstall the classic editor plugin and it will resolve it.